# Is there a way to check if a program is available in the repository by commandline?

Tags: command-line, package-management, apt, aptitude, repository

When i find a interesting program i want to test and install in ubuntu i first check if it's available in the repository. For that i use the software center.

But does a possibility exist to check it via commandline i.e. apt or aptitude?
Similar apt get install command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use any one of these commands,

`apt-cache search <package_name>`

`aptitude search <package_name>`

`apt-cache policy <package_name>`

`sudo apt-get install <package_name> -s`

**Output:**

```
karthick@Ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk -s
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jdk has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You can prefix the keyword with `^` to denote starts-with, for example `aptitude search ^deb` which will list package names start with `deb` instead of contain `deb`. There maybe more control chars in the regex, but I don't know any more.

Answer (score 4):

You can install `apt-file` which allows you to search for file names in APT. For instances to find a binary `nagios`

```
marco@marco-desktop:~$ sudo apt-file search nagios3
aide-common: /usr/share/aide/config/aide/aide.conf.d/31_aide_nagios3
cherokee-doc: /usr/share/doc/cherokee-doc/media/images/cookbook_nagios3.png
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/andrade
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/base
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/bernhard
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/cook
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/didier
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/remus
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/satrapa
nagios-images: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images/logos/werschler
nagios3: /usr/share/doc/nagios3
nagios3: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/nagios3
nagios3-cgi: /etc/nagios3/cgi.cfg
nagios3-cgi: /etc/nagios3/stylesheets/avail.css
nagios3-cgi: /etc/nagios3/stylesheets/checksanity.css
nagios3-cgi: /etc/nagios3/stylesheets/cmd.css
nagios3-cgi: /etc/nagios3/stylesheets/common.css
nagios3-cgi: /etc/nagios3/stylesheets/config.css
```

It breaks down by `package: file match`

Answer (score 3):

`apt-cache search` is what you want:

For example:

```
apt-cache search firefox
```

will return things with firefox in it. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html):

> search performs a full text search on all available package lists
>              for the POSIX regex pattern given, see [regex(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man7/regex.7.html). It searches the
>              package names and the descriptions for an occurrence of the regular
>              expression and prints out the package name and the short
>              description, including virtual package names. If --full is given
>              then output identical to show is produced for each matched package,
>              and if --names-only is given then the long description is not
>              searched, only the package name is.
>
> Separate arguments can be used to specify multiple search patterns
>              that are and'ed together.