# How to install dhcpd3?

Tags: dhcpd

As I recall, there used to be this DHCP server called dhcpd3
However, under ubuntu, I am not entirely sure where to obtain or how to install it.
The following command doesn't seem to locate the package.

```
apt-get install dhcpd3

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dhcpd3
```

Has dhcpd3 been deprecated and replaced by something else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If apt-get reports "unable to locate" on a package that should be there, you can usually find out it's name by doing something like `apt-cache search dhcp3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server name is actually `dhcp3-server`

This is actually a [transitional package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20377/what-exact-purpose-have-transitional-packages) to the actual DHCP server that is shipped, which is `isc-dhcp-server`

More info on how to search packages here:

- [Is there a way to check if a program is available in the repository by commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18939/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-program-is-available-in-the-repository-by-commandlin)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server
```